# UWP Image control size not changing when binding value is changed

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have an image control with the height and width bound to a property as follows:

```xml
<Image x:Name="capturedPhoto" Height="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairHeight, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairWidth, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

And I have number boxes bound to the same properties.

```xml
<muxc:NumberBox Value="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
<muxc:NumberBox Value="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
```

When I change the value of the number box at run time, the image size doesn't change.

Comment: Have you checked my reply about UWP Image control size not changing?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that `CrosshairHeight` and `CrosshairWidth` are not implemented with `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You need to either implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use bindings directly:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <muxc:NumberBox
        Header="Height"
        Value="{x:Bind AwesomeImage.Height, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <muxc:NumberBox
        Header="Width"
        Value="{x:Bind AwesomeImage.Width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Image
        x:Name="AwesomeImage"
        Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png"
        Stretch="Fill" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions, one is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as @Andrew said, and the other is to directly use `binding` to bind the value of NumberBox. The second method is simpler if you are only implementing simple size changes with values

#### -Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
<Image x:Name="capturedPhoto"  Height="{x:Bind  Path=imageCls.CrosshairHeight, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{x:Bind Path=imageCls.CrosshairWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Loaded="capturedPhoto_Loaded"/>
<muxc:NumberBox Value="{x:Bind Path=imageCls.CrosshairHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"/>
<muxc:NumberBox Value="{x:Bind Path=imageCls.CrosshairWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"/>
```

---

```
public imageCls imageCls = new imageCls();
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    imageCls.CrosshairWidth = 300;
    imageCls.crosshairHeight = 100;
}


//-------------------------------------------------------
// This is a new class
public class imageCls : INotifyPropertyChanged   
{
    public double crosshairHeight, crosshairWidth;

    public double CrosshairHeight 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.crosshairHeight;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.crosshairHeight != value)
            {
                crosshairHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CrosshairHeight");
            }
        }
    }
    public double CrosshairWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.crosshairWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.crosshairWidth != value)
            {
                crosshairWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CrosshairWidth");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

#### -Bind the value of NumberBox

```
<Image x:Name="capturedPhoto"  Height="{Binding ElementName=num1, Path=Value}" Width="{Binding ElementName=num2, Path=Value}" />
<muxc:NumberBox x:Name="num1" Value="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"/>
<muxc:NumberBox x:Name="num2" Value="{x:Bind Path=CrosshairWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Inline"/>
```